# Integral Of $\int \frac{2\cdot \cos^2(x)}{x^2}dx$

Tags: integration

I`m trying to integrate the following:
$$\int\frac{2\cdot \cos^2(x)}{x^2}dx$$
what I did first is:
$$\int \frac{2\cdot (\frac{1}{2}+\frac{cos2x}{2})}{x^2}dx=\int \frac{1+cos2x}{x^2}dx$$
now what? any suggestions? thanks!

Comment: Do you mean $\cos^2 x$ instead of $\cos x^2$?

Comment: I changed it. thanks.

Comment: You will not be able to express this integral in terms of the elementary functions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a simple integration by parts, we arrive at the following expression, which, as has already mentioned above, is irreducible to elementary functions: $$F(x)=-2\left[\frac{\cos^2x}x+\text{Si}(2x)\right]$$ where $\text{Si}(t)=\int\frac{\sin x}x dx$.